# Java Generics beginner - Compiler warning on type safe declaration and instantiation

Tags: java, generics

The compiler throws in a warning if i declare and instantiate a new type safe collection like below

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(); // compiler warning
List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<String>(); //this is normal and ok.
```

The list object seems to be type safe as I can't put in any other object other than String in it. So, are there any pitfalls of using such a declaration ?

Comment: You're right, in this case it's safe, but if you've got the declaration and instantiation separate you'll be glad to see a warning like this to remind you to use typed collections as to avoid runtime surprises. It would be a good thing for you to get in the habit of specifying types wherever possible.

Comment: In the current version of Java SE, you can write `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. Pity you can't write, say, `List<String> list = new();`, but it's a little bit of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you could have done something like this:

```
ArrayList foo = new ArrayList();
foo.add(new Integer(5));
List<String> list = foo;  // compiler warning
```

But this would break the contract that a `List<String>` should only contain `String`s.  So that is why you get the warning; in general mixing raw and generic types is bad practice.

Comment: His warning is likely from the use of raw types. How does this help?

Comment: @Shakedown: I'm demonstrating the kind of problem that that warning is designed to help identify.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by pitfalls.  I would say no.  The generic ensures that your List will accept only Strings.  I think that's a good thing.  If you need a List in which you need to store something other than Strings, then this won't work.  Even then, I would consider whether I can create a custom class that would accept the types of values needed, and then create a generic List with the custom class:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```